# Terraform to provision EC2 managed PEM File (for SSH)

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, terraform, rsa, terraform-provider-aws

I am using Terraform to provision EC2 Server. Before provisioning EC2 server, I want to provision AWS Managed Key pair (PEM File) with terraform, download it in my local and use that key to create EC2 instances in future.

In Terraform registry for key pair, I have found this code:

```
resource "aws_key_pair" "deployer" {
  key_name   = "deployer-key"
  public_key = "ssh-rsa AAAAB3NzaC1yc2EAAAADAQABAAABAQD3F6tyPEFEzV0LX3X8BsXdMsQz1x2cEikKDEY0aIj41qgxMCP/iteneqXSIFZBp5vizPvaoIR3Um9xK7PGoW8giupGn+EPuxIA4cDM4vzOqOkiMPhz5XK0whEjkVzTo4+S0puvDZuwIsdiW9mxhJc7tgBNL0cYlWSYVkz4G/fslNfRPW5mYAM49f4fhtxPb5ok4Q2Lg9dPKVHO/Bgeu5woMc7RY0p1ej6D4CKFE6lymSDJpW0YHX/wqE9+cfEauh7xZcG0q9t2ta6F6fmX0agvpFyZo8aFbXeUBr7osSCJNgvavWbM/06niWrOvYX2xwWdhXmXSrbX8ZbabVohBK41 email@example.com"
}
```

In the above Terraform code, it asks for my public key. But, I don't want to use my own public key. I want to provision the default from AWS Console.

How can I provision the AWS Managed Key pair and download it from Terraform code?

Comment: Exact duplicate of a question that was closed for being off-topic.

Answer (score 0):

What you require is **not supported**. [aws_key_pair](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/aws/latest/docs/resources/key_pair) is used to register an **existing** new public key with AWS. This means that you need to have corresponding private key available locally.

To login to the instance you **need private key**. Public key is not enough. Also you can't download them from AWS if you already don't have them available. **AWS does not store private keys**. Only public keys are stored.

You can create new key using [tls_private_key](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/tls/latest/docs/resources/private_key) if you want to keep everything under control of terraform. But if you are not OK with its security issues, you can use `ssh-keygen` to generate a new key pair as you would normally do when not using terraform.

Comment: why not store pub and private key in secrets manager?

Answer (score 0):

As @Marcin suggested, you can't download AWS private key. Instead of this, you can create public and private keys locally and upload public key to AWS. You can use later the private key stored locally for EC2 login.
For the reference, see the code here: https://github.com/dumrauf/openvpn-terraform-install/blob/master/ec2.tf